# Splitting polygon into different regions using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Is there any way that I can divide the below image into different areas?

Just like a Google Map, where you can see the country borders.

I am using ArcMap 10.0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your image is just a single polygon then it's unlikely you'll be able to just 'split' it into countries as it may not have this spatial information attached to it.

Your best option is probably to try and obtain shapefiles of individual country outlines and georeference / superimpose these on your image.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a background like in Google Earth, you can click on the little black arrow next to the "add layer" button and select "add basemap", then you can choose , e.g., "light grey Canvas".

If you need the polygons for analysis, you can download Administrative areas [here](http://gadm.org/) (GADM) and more resources are to be found [here](http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/)(Free GIS data list by R. Wilson)